# How do I fix a NullPointerException on Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner in programming and I am trying to solve a math problem on Kotlin. The problem is:

"Challenge -> You must read 5 integer values. Then show how many reported values ​​are even, how many reported values ​​are odd, how many reported values ​​are positive, and how many reported values ​​are negative. Assume that the number zero is positive, but it cannot be considered positive or negative.

Input -> You will receive 5 integer values (-5, 0, -3, -4, 12).

Exit -> Display the message as shown in the output example below, being one message per line and not forgetting the end of the line after each one. The output should show (3 evens, 2 odds, 1 positive, 3 negatives)"

This was what I thought could be the solution:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

  val integers= mutableListOf<Int>()
  var evens = mutableListOf<Int>()
  var odds = mutableListOf<Int>()
  var positives = mutableListOf<Int>()
  var negatives = mutableListOf<Int>()

  for (i in 1..5) { integers.add(readLine()!!.toInt()) }

  for (i in integers) { 
    if (i % 2 == 0) { evens.add(i) }
    if (i % 2 != 0) { odds.add(i) }
    if (i > 0) { positives.add(i) }
    if (i < 0) { negatives.add(i) }
  }

  println("${evens.size} even(s)")
  println("${odds.size} odd(s)")
  println("${positives.size} positive(s)")
  println("${negatives.size} negative(s)")

}
```

This is returning the following message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
> at FileKt.main (File.kt:9) 
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) 
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

How can I fix it? What did I do wrong? What am I forgetting?

Comment: The root cause of the issue is `readLine()!!`. For some reason, `readLine()` is null. How are you running the code?

Comment: This is exactly why `readLine()` returns a _nullable_ String — it could be null if there's no more input. That could be because input has been redirected from a file, and you've reached the end of it; or because input is from the keyboard, and the user has typed the end-of-file character (e.g. Ctrl+D on macOS and Linux); or because you're running on an online IDE that doesn't support an input stream.

Comment: The `!!` is a code smell — it indicates that a NullPointerException is possible. (Unless you know something the compiler doesn't, which is less common than you might think!) Any time you find yourself writing `!!`, you should stop and ask “Is there any possible way this could be null? If so, how could I handle it?”

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** You don't put any input.

**Long answer:**

[image]

If you programming in https://play.kotlinlang.org/ you gonna got that error.
Because it dont have read input.

But same example in
[image]

with input gonna be ok.

[image]